# Plotting different x-axis using facet grids

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, axis-labels

I am plotting spider-diagrams for geochemical analysis.

I managed to plot different series of elements separately (major elements and rare-earth elements) but I would like to plot them together using facet_grid. The problem I get is that the x-axis is common. I would like to have two separate x-axis like I show in the imgur post : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmjKW.jpg

I've written commented codes on what I achieved :

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


data <- read_excel("Documents/TFB/xlsx_geochimie/solfa_total_tout_ppm.xlsx", 
                   col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                 "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))

### Vectors containing different geochemical series

vec_maj = c("SiO2","TiO2","Al2O3","FeO","MgO","CaO","Na2O","K2O")
vec_TR = c("La","Ce","Pr","Nd","Sm","Eu","Gd","Tb","Dy","Ho","Er","Tm","Yb","Lu")
vec_tout <- as.character(c(vec_maj,vec_TR))
data.mod <- data[vec_tout]
data.mod$Ech <- data$Ech
### Wide format to long format
data.lf = data %>% select(c(vec_tout,"Ech")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Ech,names_to="Element",values_to="Pourcentage") %>%
  mutate(Element=factor(Element,levels=unique(vec_tout)))
### Plotting the series separately

data.maj <- subset(data.lf,data.lf$Element %in% vec_maj)
View(data.maj)
data.TR <- subset(data.lf,data.lf$Element %in% vec_TR)

ggplot(data=data.maj,mapping=aes(x=Element,y=Pourcentage,colour=Ech))+
  geom_point()+geom_line(aes(group=Ech))+scale_y_log10()

ggplot(data=data.TR,mapping=aes(x=Element,y=Pourcentage,colour=Ech))+
  geom_point()+geom_line(aes(group=Ech))+scale_y_log10()

# Plotting the series together, x-axis scales does not split :-( 
data.lf$Type <- ifelse(data.lf$Element %in% vec_maj,"Major","REE")
ggplot(data=data.lf,mapping=aes(x=Element,y=Pourcentage,colour=Ech))+
  geom_point()+geom_line(aes(group=Ech))+scale_y_log10()+facet_grid(Type~.,scales="free")
```

You may download my dataset here : [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e1oTUQtH-qrkWfM2nc8ADm1D3YBNWPBb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Couple things based on the [mcve] guidance: it's really preferable for you to have a sample of the data that reproduces the problem as text in the post rather than downloaded from a third-party. If you remove that file some day or close your Google account, the question would no longer have any of the necessary data. If the question is about plotting, you can skip over the majority of the code here, which is about reading & prepping data, and just give us the sample that needs to be plotted. Adding spaces in your code can also go a long way for readability

Comment: Have you tried the same code, but with `facet_wrap( )` instead of `facet_grid( )`?

Comment: Unrelated but an FYI: check out the `read_excel` (or any `readr` function) docs for `col_types`: you could skip that whole block of code you've got at just give a single string like `"tnnnn"`. Even better, `paste(c("t", rep("n", 20)), collapse = "")` —I just guessed 20, use however many numeric columns you actually have

Comment: You're losing 15% of your data by trying to convert to `numeric` fields like `"< 0.4"`. Since you're explicitly saying `numeric`, it's your call, but ... two fields are almost completely wiped out (`Cl` and `Mass`). Have you looked at your data once you import it to verify it is what you think it is? I would have started to worry when with 12 rows of data, `read_excel` exhibits 194 warnings.

Comment: @r2evans Yep, actually when the fields are like "< 0.x" it means that the value is under the dection limit of the analysis so converting it to numeric makes the value a n.a which is fine for my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `facet_grid`, can you use `facet_wrap`?

```r
ggplot(data.lf, mapping = aes(x = Element, y = Pourcentage, colour = Ech)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Ech)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(Type ~ ., ncol = 1, scales = "free")
# Warning: Removed 8 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image: facet wrap]

Comment: Wow I could have figured it out my self, still have a lot to learn with ggplot, thank you very much !